# Non-exhaustive patterns in function lookUp

Tags: haskell, pattern-matching

[image: This is a picture of the function defined]

I'm trying to define a function in haskell, that given a search string and a list of string/item pairs, returns the list of items whose associated string matches the search string. For example, *module>
lookUp "A" [("A",8),("B",9),("C",5),("A",7)]

Should return    [8,7].
But whenever I run this code in terminal it returns this error message.

> Non-exhaustive patterns in function lookUp.

Can someone tell me what's wrong and how I can fix it?

Comment: it should simply be `lookUp input pairs = [y | (x, y) <- pairs, x == input]`. You don't actually need to destructure the list, which appears to be what you're attempting (incorrectly) to do.

Comment: @PrakharNagpal, [don't post images of code](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode).

Comment: [This is your friend](https://stackoverflow.com/help). Click and read what you need. Then you can also edit the question and put the code instead of the image.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The pattern `[(a, b)]` only works for a list with *exactly* one element. So for lists with multiple elements, this will not work. You furthermore do not need a case for the empty list, you can write this as:

```
lookUp :: Eq k => k -> [(k, v)] -> [v]
lookUp input items = [y | (x, y) <- items, x == input]
```

Here we thus will for each pair `(x, y)` in data, check if `x == input`, and in that case emit the value in the list.